# Incrementing values in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to increment the variable `value`. When I check a box, the function `cal` runs and appends the `advert.numbers` of every item checked. How can I increment the `advert.numbers` in the variable `value`.

In my code below, I keep getting `NAN`.

How can I increment the value and pass the value to the input box with `id="values`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="values" placeholder="values" name="values">
<script type="text/javascript">
var values;
function cal(item) { 
  var advert = JSON.parse(item.dataset.name);

  if(item.checked == true) {
    $('.panel').append(
      '<div class="container">'
        + '<p class="points" data-points="' + advert.numbers + '">'
          + advert.numbers
        + '</p>'
      + '</div>'
    );

    values += advert.numbers;
    alert(values);   
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is `item.dataset.name` ? Please provide a working snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you never give `values` an initial value, so it starts out with the default initial value, which is `undefined`. `undefined` plus any number is `NaN`, because `undefined` cannot be implicitly coerced to a number.

Just start with `var values = 0;` instead of just `var values;`.

---

I'd also suggest avoiding having your code at global scope like that. The global namespace is **very** crowded (and in fact, your `var values` is shadowing a global that already exists thanks to the horror of implicit globals for elements with `id`s). Consider wrapping all of your code in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    // ...your code here...
})();
```